# How to Insert data to CloudTables database using cURL/HTTP in PHP? Error: API Key is required

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I'm inserting a row to the CloudTables database using cURL request. following is the sample cURL request available on their [documentations][1]:

```
curl \
    -X POST \
    -d key=:apiKey \
    https://sub-domain.cloudtables.io/api/1/dataset/:id
```

*Where*

- *:apiKey is the API key to use for access (see below)*
- *:id is the dataset id (a UUID),*

And below is my PHP Code:

```
    $post = array(
        'clientId' => $user_id,
        'clientName' => $user_email,
        'dp-01' => $user_id,
        'dp-02' => $user_type,
        'dp-03' => $fullname,
        'dp-04' => $address,
    );

    $ch = curl_init('https://sub-domain.cloudtables.io/api/1/dataset/my-dataset-id');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('key: my-api-key'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

***But every time response says:***

```
[
  {
     "msg":"API key is required",
     "name":"key"
  }
]
```

***Why!!! What is the right way to send API key?***

I also tried sending API key in $post array and in URL, but getting same response.
[1]: https://cloudtables.com/docs/cloud/api/rest/post-dataset

Comment: `curl -d` is not for setting values in the header, it's for data (https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d).  Try putting key and apiKey into the `$post` data.

Comment: @Alan already tried putting "key" => "APIKey" into $post but still getting same error!

Comment: Passing an array for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, will make it send a `multipart/form-data` request - maybe the API doesn't like those? Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));`, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe; It's working now!
I request you to plz post this as answer so I can mark it as solution. so it can help for others.
`
$post = array(
  'key' => 'my-api-key',
  'clientId' => $user_id,
  'clientName' => $user_email,
  'dp-01' => $user_id,
  'dp-02' => $user_type,
  'dp-03' => $fullname,
);
$ch = curl_init('https://sub-domain.cloudtables.io/api/1/dataset/my-dataset-id');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing an array for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, will make it send a `multipart/form-data` request - whereas the API apparently expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));` instead